# What's the best way to stream video from a camera on an embedded device?

Tags: linux, video, camera, embedded, video-streaming

I'm using a Samsung S3C6410 to develop a video ( currently no good solution for synchronized video and audio ) streaming application.

I intended to put this board on a small robot car and stream the video from the camera back to me from 3G network.

Up till now,  the best solution I tried is mjpg_streamer. It's a good open source project and it does what it promises to do. But what disappoints me is that the performance is not good enough.

- It uses HTTP as the way to stream video, which result in lots of wasted bandwidth. My test results for a 1280x720 video is more than 1MB/s, and for 640x480 video is about 300KB/s.
- It does not stream audio at the same time.

I found out that the Mjpg-streamer project is developing a module for RTSP streaming, but it's far from completion. So I want to know if there are open source projects that meet my requirements(bandwidth efficient, and stream audio at the same time but not necessarily solved with one software only).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use gstreamer. It is able to stream audio and video. Have a look at the udpsink and rtp modules:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp.html

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-udpsink.html